# How to resolve this Error when knit markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to knit an RMarkdown to an HTML file.
But I got an error like this

Quitting from lines 28-34 (learning_map2.Rmd)

> Error in slot(p, "Polygons") :
> cannot get a slot ("Polygons") from an object of type "NULL"
> Calls: ... createSPComment -> lapply -> FUN -> sapply -> lapply -> slot

Execution halted
screenshot_1598604180|690x133

But I can run it on my mac. It's just doesn't run in my Window PC.
Thanks all!

Comment: Is variable `p` loaded on your Windows PC? If you clear the environment variables on your Mac (`rm(list = ls())`), does it still run?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Most likely you are reading in data and the path is not right. That will cause you to get the missing (NULL) object.  Try putting the data that you are loading into the same folder as the .Rmd file.  Remember that when the markdown file is knit, it exists in its own environment.  So, an object you successfully loaded previously will not be loaded in the new (temporary) session while it knits.

Comment: p is not a variable in my file. it is an example (I think so). everything is ok in my Mac, until I used my PC to run. how to post my code or picture, so you can know more my issue?

Comment: I did it on the same folder for all process sir